# access form - "After update", go to next record, unless you're on last record?

Tags: forms

I have a form where the user clicks on a yes/no checkbox,
and the form immediately goes to the next record *'after update'* of the record (as intended)

I also have the "Allow additions" set to "no", so they can't accidentally add a new record.

So when they update the last record, the form tries to go to the next record, but there is none,
and they get an error message.

How do I get Access to do something different on the last record,
besides trying to go to this non-existent next record?

thanks

Searching google hasn't quite helped - i get partial answers to what i need, but not a complete answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've got it figured out.
This "after update" code will advance one record when the user checks (or unchecks) the yes/no field, unless it's the last record, then it just saves the record.

Private Sub TicketPulled_AfterUpdate()
With Me.Recordset
  If .AbsolutePosition = .RecordCount - 1 Then
     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
  Else
     DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
  End If
End With
End Sub


Just trying to save keystrokes by having the database auto-advance to the next record, and also save the records, in case user forgets to leave the record (thereby not saving it)